# PowerPoint to PDF: Minimum size option

Tags: vba, powershell, powerpoint

I was attempting to convert PowerPoint files to PDF using PowerShell and was able to do so. However, I am trying to take this one step further and select the 'Minimum Size (publishing online)' option through the script.

Is there a property that needs to be set for this to happen? I'm guessing it is the `$ppQualityStandard` variable but not exactly sure.

EDIT: This is what I am using currently:

```bsh
function ppt_to_pdf ($folderpath, $pptname) {
    Add-Type -AssemblyName office
    $ppFormatPDF = 2
    $ppQualityStandard = 0
    $p = New-Object -ComObject PowerPoint.Application
    $p.Visible = [Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState]::msoTrue
    $ppt = $p.Presentations.Open("$folderpath\$pptname")
    $ppt.SaveCopyAs("$folderpath\$pptname", 32)
    $ppt.Close()
    $p.Quit()
    $p = $null
    [gc]::collect()
    [gc]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
}
```

Comment: PowerShell doesn't come with PowerPoint-related cmdlets. Unless you tell us specifically what cmdlets you're using and where they came from, what you've tried, and what didn't work, you may not get an answer.

Comment: Thanks @mklement0. I have added the code currently used to convert the ppt to pdf.

Comment: Your question is primarily about Microsoft PowerPoint's VBA (COM) API; the fact that you're using PowerShell to access that API is incidental (except if you had trouble with PowerShell syntax, which doesn't appear to be the case). I've added tag `powerpoint-vba` to your question. A quick look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff744735.aspx tells me that the `.SaveCopyAs` method doesn't take a quality parameter. You may have to look for a separate utility that reduces the PDF's size after the fact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you need to use `.ExportAsFixedFormat` rather than `.SaveCopyAs`.

It takes, among other parameters, `Intent` as type `ppFixedFormatIntent`, which can be either:

`ppFixedFormatIntentScreen`  (=1)

or

`ppFixedFormatIntentPrint` (=2)

There's a host of other parms.  To learn more, start PPT, go into the VBA IDE and press F2 for the Object Browser and search for `ExportAsFixedFormat`

Comment: ++; `ppFixedFormatIntentScreen` is the default; the online documentation is at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff746080.aspx